# Can't shift into any gear even when engine is off

Tags: clutch, manual-transmission, dodge, caliber

For about a week there have been times that I've had trouble shifting into and out of gears on my 2010 Dodge Caliber.  Some days it didn't do it at all, but others I had to put the car in and out of gear with a lot of force.  Now I can't get it in gear at all and the clutch pedal has lost all resistance.  Even when the car is off, I can't get it to shift into the different gears.  Called shop and they said since it won't shift into gear when engine is off then it has to be something other than the clutch, but they had no ideas what it could be...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you're not getting any resistance against the pedal, I'd think the hydraulic master/slave cylinder would be at fault ... at least that's the first place I'd check. You can look to ensure it has fluid in the reservoir (should either be a smaller reservoir next to the brake master reservoir, or attached directly to the brake reservoir directly). If it is low, drop some new, clean DOT3/4 brake fluid in there and see if that makes a difference. Could get you down the road to the mechanic as well as tell you if there's an issue with the clutch.

Comment: When you say “can’t get it to shift” do you mean that the gear selector will not slide into the gear slots? Or that it will move into the positions, but won’t engage a gear?

Comment: As @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 said, it sounds like a clutch hydraulic problem. I had a similar issue with difficulty shifting previously, which turned out to be a master cylinder problem. Does the pedal simply fall to the floor and stay there or does it return? Does the fluid reservoir have any fluid? Do your brakes still seem to work fine?

Answer (score 1):

The shop is wrong. It's your clutch. I've had this exact problem and even with the engine off, it wouldn't go into gear. You probably have a leak and the hydraulic clutch fluid has leaked out enough that it won't work. Top it up and take it to a different shop to have the leak fixed.